# what the difference between Pearson correlation and Kendall's tau tests can tell us?

Tags: correlation, pearson-r, kendall-tau

i plotted Pearson correlation with p-values of the insignificant correlations and did the same for Kendall's tau, then i have computed the difference between the two tests, and obtained the below plot, but it was unclear to me to interpret the difference. Any explanation will be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]